# Different Doris search delay when giving the same condition with different data type

Tags: sql, olap, apache-doris

I am using Apache Doris as database.

My query be like

```
select city
from table
where city_id in (xxx) and {{other condition}}
```

I keep the other condition same and query this clause with xxx as '123' and 123.
It costs 30s when I give the 「xxx」 as string, but only costs 3s when I give the 「xxx」 as int.

Just wondering what lead to such huge difference in delay.

Answer (score 0):

There are many aspects that may be affected:

- Int is naturally more efficient than string（Less CPU cost, less memory cost, less I/O）;
- String type of data cannot use prefix sorting index;
- Int type of data can realize fast positioning and data filtering through prefix index;
- There are many ways to improve the performance of a SQL.

To be honest, it doesn't look good to finish such a simple query in 3 seconds. Try reach out to the Apache Doris community for further assistance.

[Discussion on Github](https://github.com/apache/doris/discussions)

[Apache Doris Slack Community](https://apachedoriscommunity.slack.com/ssb/redirect)

Comment: Thx for ur comment. My table has 2T data and mainly contains a lot of chinese (also will be included in other condition). I think that's the reason why it costs 3 secs. And it's really helpful to learn string cannot use prefix sorting index. I thought it would and built some rollup based on string columns to speed up the query lol.

Answer (score 0):

Katherine,

First of all I would like to ask which doris version you are using?

Second, can you post your table creation statement?

I suspect your `city_id` field is in the prefix index range, querying with `int` will be fast. Using a string query will convert the table data into a string for filtering, so that the prefix index is not used, resulting in a great difference in the efficiency of the two queries.

In the next new version we implemented an inverted index, I think this will be very helpful for string filtering queries: https://doris.apache.org/docs/dev/data-table/index/inverted-index/